# php: json_encode test when utf-8 fails

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have issues with failed UTF-8 character encodings in a database.
When i read it with php and `json_encode()`, `json_encode($content)` fails and gives an empty string back.

```
$test = array('meep' => base64_decode('7b6Y'));
echo json_encode($test)."\n";

if(json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_UTF8) {
    echo "fail\n";
}
```

Tell me why this does not print anything else then "fail". Or better, what was the input content.

1. Is there a way to detect JSON_ERROR_UTF8 without calling json_encode needless. Like json_test or something else?
2. Do you know a method to repair a misspelled utf-8 string? Back to hex cut the problem and back to utf-8 or something else?

In this case answers with the target to store the string better are useless!

Comment: If you want to check whether a string is valid in a particular encoding, use `mb_check_encoding`.

Comment: You should never have to guess what encoding any particular string is in. Why don't you know whether something coming from your database is UTF-8 or not? You control that by setting the connection encoding when connecting to the database.

Comment: Using `utf8_encode` on arbitrary strings doesn't *fix* them, it just ensures that you have something that's valid in the UTF-8 encoding, but it may or may not be complete garbage.

Comment: Works for me and looks better in a loop...
The problem is that a bad unicode sequence was written in an utf8mb4 mysql field.
This can happen again and async reload with js and json fails in this cases.
Of course, the field encoding is utf-8 ever, but the value that was written couldt contain bad unicode sequences.
This is possible with emoji sequences with surregate pairs and combined enclosing keycaps. In the future web apps shouldt expect that.

Comment: P.S. the utf8_encode($content); is only an easy to read example.
After that json_encode works, but other characters fails evident.

Comment: I suggest you detail your actual problem a bit more and not focus on this hackaround. A database configured to use `utf8mb4` should not return invalid UTF-8; if you can somehow make it do that anyway, show us how and we can maybe help you not make it do that.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the input to `json_encode` is *not valid UTF-8* (it's some random binary gibberish). All strings passed to `json_encode` Must. Be. Valid. UTF-8. Period. If you want to pass arbitrary binary data, you need to encode it in a portable format, e.g. base 64 encoded.

Comment: Yes, i allready knew that and the example that youve read and deleted is from a mysql utf8mb4 field. The string was read with the php mysqli lib and i wouldt try to send this in json. When i convert it to base64 (with or without mysql functions) -> send it in json and decode it with js atob() all specialchars are destroyed. Even not practical...

This time i does not know the INSERT Statement that make this garbage in the varchar utf8mb4 field!

Comment: Well, we're going in circles… If you put invalid UTF-8 into `json_encode` it's going to bomb out, we've established that. **Concentrate on where that invalid UTF-8 comes from.** Demonstrate how you're using mysqli so it returns invalid UTF-8 from a utf8mb4 database.

Comment: The answer to this question:

Ok, it is possible to fill a utf8_mb4 field with a wasted value.
Also it is possible to read the wasted value after that.
I emanate that not all of it can happen.

My Problem:

I cant show a complete example, but fill a Textarea with: '\ud83d\ude01' using Javascript.
Send it and store it. It gives waste, but the client is experimental.
Then use the EDGE Brower and send it again. Also waste but in this case json_encode crashes.
If i figure out some better examples, i will open a new question...

Answer (score 0):

It IS possible to write worst in a field, with a predefined charset!

If the data cannot be restored and it must fixed fast?!
Here is a dirty but not a total loss method, to prevent the crash with json_encode():

```
if(!mb_check_encoding($oldContent, "UTF-8")) {
    $newContent = '';
    for($e = 0; $e < count($oldContent); $e++) {
        if(mb_check_encoding($oldContent[$e], "UTF-8")) {
            $newContent .= $oldContent[$e];
        } else {
            trigger_error("Bad char at ".$e);
        }
    }
    $oldContent = $newContent;
}
```